# ASP.NET MVC 5 : using Application Variable to create a Online User counter

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I come into a problem that probably is something dumb but I´ve just looked all over the places and just can´t make this work!

I have a ASP.NET MVC web application created, and I want to use the Application["something"] to save a counter to mark visitors online. I had done a couple of times this process in ASP.NET , not in MVC...

So, on Global.asax, I have the following code

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        HttpContext.Current.Application["totalVisitas"] = 0;
        HttpContext.Current.Application["visitasOnline"] = 0;
}
```

And after that I created a Model to use this data and a Controller also with the following code:

```
 public class OnlineStatsController : Controller
    {
        // GET: OnlineStats
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

        var modelOnline = new OnlineStatsViewModel
        {
            visitasOnline = (int)HttpContext.Application["visitasOnline"],
            totalVisitas = (int)HttpContext.Application["totalVisitas"]

        };
        return PartialView("UserStats",modelOnline);
    }
}
```

ViewModel Code :

```
public class OnlineStatsViewModel
    {
        public int totalVisitas { get; set; }

        public int visitasOnline { get; set; }


    }
}
```

Finally, I have a partial view with the following code:

```
@model  {namespace}.Models.OnlineStatsViewModel



    <h3>Visitas online: </h3>
    <p id="visitasOnline">@Model.visitasOnline</p>
    <h3>Total de Visitas: </h3>
    <p id="totalVisitas"><span class="badge">@Model.totalVisitas </span></p>
```

And it is called by the layout.cshtml

```
<body>
    @Html.Partial("_topBar")
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year -</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                   @Html.Partial("UserStats",  new {namespace}.Models.OnlineStatsViewModel());
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
```

All this, and everytime it load, it gives 0 users online and 0 historic. I even tried to hardcode the value in the controller making something like visitasOnline = 20000; but it only shows zero ... Sorry if the question is dumb, I´m tottaly newbie in MVC and trying a few courses online and got this problem =(

EDIT --- Forgot to write where I update

In global.asax I have the following also:

```
 public void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when a new session is started
            HttpContext.Current.Session["userName"] = "guest";
            HttpContext.Current.Application["visitasOnline"] = (int)HttpContext.Current.Application["visitasOnline"] +1;
            HttpContext.Current.Application["totalVisitas"] = (int)HttpContext.Current.Application["totalVisitas"] +1;
        }

        public void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Code that runs when a session ends. 
            // Note: The Session_End event is raised only when the sessionstate mode
            // is set to InProc in the Web.config file. If session mode is set to StateServer 
            // or SQLServer, the event is not raised.
            HttpContext.Current.Session["userName"] = "";
            HttpContext.Current.Application["visitasOnline"] = (int)HttpContext.Current.Application["visitasOnline"] - 1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your model *reads* the current value from the application-level values.  But where do you ever *write* to the application-level values?  Aside from originally setting them to zero, you never update them.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that part, will update, I update them in the global.asax

Comment: Do you change the values at all?

Comment: You create *two* instances of `OnlineStatsViewModel`.  One of them sets the values, the other does not.  Maybe the output you're seeing is from that second one?  What happens if you set the values in the model's constructor instead of in the controller?

Comment: Will try it and will post the info here for you, just need a few time as my laptop now is on strike and does not want to work!

Comment: Could you post some part of your web configuration, specifically the <sessionState> element

Answer (score 0):

With the limited information about the session store, The possibility of having such an issue could be you might have followed the path as given below:

1. You wrote the code to increment the value after one or two times debugging the app.
2. Because your session might not have expired yet, The `Session_start` is not again called where you later added the code to increment the value. and thus giving the value **0**

   To verify if this is the underlying issue, Force the app to call `Session_Start` again by opening the application URL in another browser or set the `sessionTimeout` to a low value in `Web.config`

I will improve this answer if more information is given, But I think this could be the issue as you code is working as it should be with me

Comment: Hello! First, let me thank you for the answer, but it didn´t work. I had set the timeout to a very low, and I also tryed to open in Mozilla and edge and chrome and no go also.